# How does MySQL 5.1 use indexes?

Tags: query, index, mysql-5.1

I've read the docs for MySQL v5.1.x on how about the indexes are used, but I'm not sure I understood it properly.

Suppose having the following MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spec_99_4_1_attivita` (
    `id_attivita` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_gruppo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_valutazione` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_azienda` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `id_sede` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `revisione_documento` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_attivita`,`id_gruppo`,`id_valutazione`,`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_id_attivita_spec_99_4_1_attivita` FOREIGN KEY (`id_attivita`, `id_azienda`, `id_sede`, `revisione_documento`) REFERENCES `gen_12_1_aree_lavoro` (`id_area_lavoro`, `id_azienda`, `id_sede`, `revisione_documento`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_id_gruppo_spec_99_4_1_attivita` FOREIGN KEY (`id_gruppo`, `id_valutazione`, `id_azienda`, `id_sede`, `revisione_documento`) REFERENCES `spec_99_4_1_gruppi` (`id_gruppo`, `id_valutazione`, `id_azienda`, `id_sede`, `revisione_documento`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

would a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM spec_99_4_1_attivita WHERE id_azienda = 1 AND id_sede = 2 AND revisione_documento = 3 AND id_valutazione = 4 AND id_gruppo = 5
```

use the indexes, or would it require a full table scan?

And, more in general, how would you determine if a query is going to use indexes or not? Could you make some general examples for both cases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use EXPLAIN to *predict* performance of a MySQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789521/how-do-i-use-explain-to-predict-performance-of-a-mysql-query)